# Indexing into a nested array of arbitrary dimension?

Tags: python

I currently have a nested array of n dimensions where n is variable.  The value of n is determined at run time.

Given an input index (i1,i2,...,in), how would I access the item in the nested array at this particular index?

For example, consider the case where n = 3 and a 3X3X3 array.

```
nested_array = [
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
]
```

and I would like to invoke the method:

```
array.insert((1,1,1), new_item)
```

where I would like the item at index (1,1,1) to be set to new_item.

As far as I know, I can not index into the array using array[1][1][1] because the dimension is unknown until run time.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly - the most you can do is try an attempt, and catch the `IndexError` exception if its raised. This will tell you that you are out of bounds for the structure.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `nested_array[index]` where index is a tuple of unknown length?

Comment: I think [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) supports N-dimensional arrays in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.array` can be accessed as `array[index]` where `index` is a tuple.

If you can not use numpy, you can get `array[index[0]][index[1]][...]` like this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], index, array)
```

and set like this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], index[:-1], array)[index[-1]] = new_value
```

operator `lambda x, y: x[y]` can be replaced with `getitem` in the `operator` module.